# secure way to make a connection between ansible awx and a VM on azure

Tags: azure, security, ansible-awx

I have a public VM on azure which I need to make private , I have ansible awx to make some installations and configurations on it in the future, what is the best and most secure way to establish the connection without exposing the VM to the internet

Until now, the solution I came up with is making connection via VPN , either azure VPN or a third-party VBN

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, the best way to establish a secure connection between your "on Prem" site and the Azure VM is creating a VPN tunnel.
If you cannot create the VPN tunnel, another "potential" solution able to reduce the VM exposure is using [Azure JIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/just-in-time-access-usage): in an automated fashion, you can enable the TCP port (used by Ansible) just the time needed for the installation and configuration tasks.